# How can I retrieve only the value of a field in model A as the field value in model B in django

Tags: django

I have 2 models named Category and Product. I want to retrieve only the id fields value in the Category model as my forign key field value in my Product model. At the minute when I retrieve a product the whole model is listed in the foreign key field in my product model. So for example rather than retrieve all the fields in the Category table I only want to retrieve the id value from the category model into the product foreign key field.

Apologies if I am not making sense but hopefully the code can clarify what I am taking about.

***Category Model***

```
class Category(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, blank=False, auto_created=True, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    category_description = models.TextField(max_length=400, blank=False)
    category_image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_path, default='', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)
```

***Product Model***

```
class Product(models.Model):
    
        (pink, 'Pink'),
    ]

    product_code = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, auto_created=True, blank=False, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
    price = models.DecimalField(default=0, max_digits=1000, decimal_places=2)
    product_image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_path, default='', blank=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, to_field='id', null=True, default='', blank=False, on_delete=models.PROTECT
```

So when I retrieve a product this is what I get:

```
"product_code": 1,
"name": "Test Product",
"price": "1.00",
"product_image": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/images/Test%20Product/91WgL3IbNIL._AC_SL1500_.jpg",
"category": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Test Category",
            "category_description": "testing",
            "category_image": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/images/Test%20Category/Image.png"
        }
```

And this is what I want to get:

```
"product_code": 1,
"name": "Test Product",
"price": "1.00",
"product_image": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/images/Test%20Product/91WgL3IbNIL._AC_SL1500_.jpg",
"category": 1
```

I tried 'to_field' and set it to id but this didn't work as it is still retrieving all the fields from the Category model. Any help would be appreciated !

Serializers

```
class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'category_description', 'category_image']


class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category = CategorySerializer(many=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['product_code', 'name', 'price', 'product_image', 'category']
```

Comment: please, share your serializer

Comment: I have added the serializers to the question for you to view @MahmoudAdel

Comment: does @gdef_'s answer solve your problem?

Comment: @MahmoudAdel yes it did thank you !

Comment: great to hear, you welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want the id you don't need to specify a custom serializer, by default it will just show the related id.

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['product_code', 'name', 'price', 'product_image', 'category']
```

If you want a serializer with less fields you need to create a new `Category` serializer with less information and use that one in your response. Or remove the extra fields that you don't want.

Comment: Great thank you, I removed the category serializer from the product serializer and that did the trick, Thanks for your help !!